# Issue with onNotification Function Not Triggering in React Native

Tags: push-notification, uilocalnotification, react-native-navigation, react-native-push-notification, react-native-notifications

fellow React Native developers!
I’m encountering an issue with local notifications in my React Native app. Specifically, the onNotification function isn’t being triggered when a notification is received/clicked. I need to handle navigation based on the notification click, but since the function isn’t firing, I’m unable to capture the event.
Here’s a brief overview of my setup:
React Native version: “0.72.4”,
Device/Emulator: iPhone X (real device) and emulators
I’ve configured my PushNotification in the following way:

```
PushNotification.configure({
  // ... other configurations ...
  onNotification: function(notification) {
    console.log('Notification Received', notification);
    // Navigation logic here
  },
});
```

The notifications are being received correctly, and everything else seems to be working fine. However, when I click on a notification, nothing happens — no console log, no navigation, nothing.
Here’s what I’ve checked so far:
Verified that other console logs work properly, and notifications are received.
Checked the library versions for compatibility.
Made sure the app requests and receives the correct permissions.
I’m at a bit of a loss here and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have. Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone know what might be going wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help!

In my React Native app, I attempted to configure local notifications using the react-native-push-notification library. I expected the onNotification function to be triggered when a notification is clicked, allowing me to handle navigation to specific screens based on the notification data.

What I tried:

Configuring the onNotification function within PushNotification.configure.
Ensuring that the app has the correct permissions to receive notifications.
Testing on both real device and emulators to check for consistent behavior.
What I expected:

The onNotification function to log the notification details in the console.
Navigation to occur based on the interaction with the notification.
What actually happened:

The notifications were received correctly but clicking them did not trigger the onNotification function.
There was no console log output or navigation action upon notification click.